# Unable to translate menu item sonata_user

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I am having difficulties translating the default user menu drop down which comes with `SonataUserBundle`. You can see the drop down menu in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot of menu]

The `admin_monogodb.yml` contains:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="sonata.user.admin.groupname">sonata_user</parameter>
</parameters>
```

And the `<services>` contain the tag (shortened):

```
<tag 
    name="sonata.admin" 
    manager_type="doctrine_mongodb"
    group="%sonata.user.admin.groupname%" 
    label="users" 
    label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore"
/>
```

As with any other translation, I simply add a entry in the `SonataUserBundle.nl.xliff`:

```
<trans-unit id="sonata_user">
    <source>sonata_user</source>
    <target>Gebruikers111</target>
</trans-unit>
```

But it still shows `sonata_user`.

I have debugged the catalogue in `Translator` and it actually **does** contain the correct translation.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging deep in the `Translator` component, I was suprised to see that it was looking for the `sonata_user` translation in the `SonataAdminBundle` domain. I have moved the translation from the `SonataUserBundle` to the `SonataAdminBundle` and now it works.